# ggplot - plot only the colourbar

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar

I wish to plot only the colourbar, if possible at the center of the window, like this :

[image]

One example where I can't remove the points, axis and background.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("viridis")    

df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), y = c(7,4,9,2,6,7))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_viridis()
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Do you mean just the legend without the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `ggpubr` has a function for exactly this need.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), y = c(7,4,9,2,6,7))

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_viridis() +
  theme_minimal()

# ggpubr does this for you
library(ggpubr)
leg <- get_legend(p)
as_ggplot(leg)
```

[image]